# Having trouble understanding the out put of the program. Interface

Tags: java, interface

I have had this question on my midterm and I struggled to answer it.
I do not understand how interfaces work. Could someone explain it to me, please?
The question was to write the output of the program like this:

Output line#1

Output line#2

Output line#3

Output line#4

Output line#5

I have tried computing the program and still could not understand...

The program is right here;

PolyMorph class:

```
public class PolyMorph{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Worker w1 = new B(); // line #1
        Worker w2 = new C(); // line #2
        w2.collaborate(w1);  // line #3
        w1.collaborate(w2);  // line #4
        System.out.println("Who gets fired?"); // line #5
    }
}
```

interface:

```
interface Worker {
    public void collaborate(Worker worker);
    public void snooze();
}
```

class A:

```
class A implements Worker{
    private String name;
    public A(){
        this("New guy!");
    }
    public A (String s){
        name = s;
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public void collaborate(Worker worker){
        worker.snooze();
    }
    public void snooze(){
        System.out.println("Zzzz");
    }
}
```

class B:

```
class B extends A{
    public B(){
        System.out.println("This is B reporting");
    }
    public B(String s){
        super(s);
    }
    public void snooze(){
        System.out.println("Watch out for the boss!");
        super.snooze();
    }
}
```

class C:

```
class C extends B{
    public C(){
        System.out.println("It's C here!");
    }
    public void snooze(){
        System.out.println("Do this till 5pm.");
    }
    public void collaborate(Worker w){
        System.out.println("Try to work together...");
        super.collaborate(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use interfaces as a way to callback stuff.

Comment: `interface` is used as part of polymorphism, amongst other things.  It allows a "object" to act as a different type (by guaranteeing to implement the function described by the `interface`.  For example `Apple` may be considered `Fruit`, so it can be passed to `Bowl`, where as `Cat`, is not a `Fruit`, so can't be passed to `Bowl`. Clear as mud :P

Answer (score 0):

Here, at line 1 and 2 you need to understand how dynamic polymorphism is working and the sequence of invocation of constructors.

Since `Worker` interface is implement by class `A` and class `A` is inherited by class `B` and class `C`, therefore, it is possible to create objects of class `B` and class `C` with the reference of `Worker` interface. So, when the objects of class `B` or class `C` will be created, the constructor of parent class `A` will be invoked first of all, then the execution of child class constructor will happen

Therefore, at line#1 the output will be :

```
New guy!
This is B reporting
```

and at line#2 the output will be :

```
New guy!
It's C here!
```

Now at line 3 and 4 , you need to understand which object you are passing as an argument in the *collaboration* method and with which object you are invoking it.

At line#3, `collaboration` method is invoked by the object of class `C` with the object of class `B` as parameter. Therefore, `collaboration`method of class `C` will be invoked. But since you are passing object of class `B` as parameter, therefore, further invocations would happen as per class `B` behavior.

Now `collaboration` method in class `C` has a print statement and then it passes the argument to the `collaboration` of parent class(that is , class `A`). In your case object of class `B` will be passed to the `collaboration`method in class `A`. So, in the `collaboration`method of class `A`, `snooze` method of worker object is invoked(which will be class `B` in this case), now the control will go to `snooze` method of class `B` and further execution will happen there. In `snooze` method of class `B`, the print statement is there and a call to parent class(which is class `A`) `snooze` method happens.
Thus output at line#3 will be:

```
Try to work together...
Watch out for the boss!
Zzzz
```

At line#4 ,`collaboration` method is invoked by the object of class `B` with the object of class `C` as parameter. 
Since class `B`, does not have its own implementation of `collaboration` method, therefore `collaboration` method of parent class (that is class `A`) will be invoked. In `collaboration` method of class `A`, `snooze` method of argument is invoked (which is the object of class `C`), therefore the output is :

```
Do this till 5pm.
```

At line#5, the output is straight forward:

```
Who gets fired?
```

The answer is quite descriptive, please read the answer carefully...